# Calculate and display sum of input fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this cart-checkout page. [Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTT00.png)
 I need to calculate the total sum of the prices and display it in the below `<div>`

This is the html:

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <a href='#' remove_id='$pid' class='btn btn-danger remove'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'>
                  </span>
    </a>
    <a href='#' update_id='$pid' class='btn btn-success update'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'>
                  </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <img src='assets/prod_images/$product_image' width='60px' height='60px'>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-2'>$product_title</div>

  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <input class='form-control price' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='price-$pid' value='$product_price' disabled>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <input class='form-control qty' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='qty-$pid' value='$qty'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <input class='value form-control price' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='amt-$pid' value='$total' disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help you with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: tell me why .each() is not working then, just?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var total = 0;
$('input.price').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$('input.total').val(total);
```

Comment: There is still a little bit of thinking to do of course. Replace your price class in your total input by a total class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the html, here is a function which will return the total price:

```
function getTotalPrice() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($("input.price.value"), function(index, item) {
        total += parseFloat($(item).val());
    });
    return total;
}
```

Then you can set the total price in the html of the `<div>` element for example like this (you should use the correct selector):

```
$("div").html(getTotalPrice());
```